# PHPExcel negative values displayed as text

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have downloaded the latest version of PHPExcel but I'm still having problems with storing the negative values in excel files.

The negative value is being shown as

```
<span class="neg">$-4,812.26</span>
```

The value is being stored in $budg and  I'm using `format_currency($budg)` to have it in the correct format.

Comment: DON'T FORMAT IT AS CURRENCY IN PHP.... store it in PHPExcel as a number, and use Excel/PHPExcel cell number-formatting... if you format it in PHP with a currency symbol and thousands separator commas it can only ever be a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A1',$budg);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('$#,##0.00');
```